# amanda client 3.3.5 for RHEL 5 - dependency issues

Tags: yum, rpm, amanda

Im working to update my various clients to use the latest version of **Amanda**. The installs work great for RHEL6 but fails on v5 with the following errors:

```
# yum localinstall amanda-backup_client-3.3.5-1.rhel5.x86_64.rpm
Loaded plugins: dellsysid, rhnplugin, security
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
Setting up Local Package Process
Examining amanda-backup_client-3.3.5-1.rhel5.x86_64.rpm: amanda-backup_client-3.3.5-  1.rhel5.x86_64
Marking amanda-backup_client-3.3.5-1.rhel5.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Excluding Packages from Red Hat Enterprise Linux (v. 5 for 64-bit x86_64)
Finished
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package amanda-backup_client.x86_64 0:3.3.5-1.rhel5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: perl(JSON) for package: amanda-backup_client
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
amanda-backup_client-3.3.5-1.rhel5.x86_64 from /amanda-backup_client-3.3.5-1.rhel5.x86_64 has depsolving problems
--> Missing Dependency: perl(JSON) is needed by package amanda-backup_client-3.3.5-  1.rhel5.x86_64 (/amanda-backup_client-3.3.5-1.rhel5.x86_64)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(JSON) is needed by package amanda-backup_client-3.3.5-1.rhel5.x86_64 (/amanda-backup_client-3.3.5-1.rhel5.x86_64)
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                    package-cleanup --dupes
                    rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
The program package-cleanup is found in the yum-utils package.
```

I've tried using `package-cleanup` and the `--skip-broken` param but neither get any further than this. I've also tried using CPAN to find/ install this **perl(JSON)**. The module appears to install but doesn't get me any further with this.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In RHEL 6, the `perl-JSON` package is included with the distribution, but in RHEL 5 it is not. For RHEL 5 you can get it from the [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repository, which you don't seem to have installed.

Comment: I tried this on two (seemingly identical systems). Worked on one but not the other. Using `yum repolist` the # of available packages is different though the repos are the same (by name). `yum search JSON` shows the package on one system but not the other. What step did I miss?

Comment: Do you have EPEL installed, and don't have excludes defined in yum.conf?

Comment: That was the problem. Old system. Had `exclude=perl*`. TYVM.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to download the package manually from the following link.

http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/15274996/dir/redhat_el_5/com/perl-JSON-2.17-1.el5.noarch.rpm.html

Comment: Thanks for suggesting an answer. But the problem with download links is they tend to only work for a short period of time. In this case, it might be better served to explain where the RPM comes from which is what [Michael Hampton did already five years ago](https://serverfault.com/a/571509/50647).